# Album art work api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm workin on a website where i show all list of hundred to thousand songs which i played recently. I need album cover pictures for songs! Is there any free Api for that? 
I should send HTTP request and get a responce [only picture]

"I'm writing code in AJAX"

Comment: There is, and I'm sure that there's more than one reliable service. If you have some requirements that can narrow down your choices, you should state them in the question. Otherwise, just google the phrase "album covers api".

Comment: This really isn't a good question for Stack Overflow. This is asking for something you can really just search for.

Answer (score 4):

I've done something similar a few times recently.

You can use the free last.fm API http://www.last.fm/api

You will need an API key (which you get once registered) and that key must be sent in the request.

One of the methods available from the API is called track.getInfo:

http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getInfo

Using this method, you can send through the artist and track name parameters (both required) like so:

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?
    method=track.getInfo&
    api_key=b___YOUR_API_KEY___&
    artist=Cher&
    track=Believe
```

The response from this request will include a series of images for that track. The following is the album node from the full request):

```
<album position="1">
    <artist>Cher</artist>
    <title>The Very Best of Cher</title>
    <mbid>00d677bf-46f2-34a4-86ad-e922d8466943</mbid>
    <url>
        http://www.last.fm/music/Cher/The+Very+Best+of+Cher
    </url>
    <image size="small">
        http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/41161483.png</image>
    <image size="medium">
        http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/41161483.png</image>
    <image size="large">
        http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/41161483.png
    </image>
    <image size="extralarge">
        http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/41161483.png
    </image>
</album>
```

You can then use your JavaScript AJAX function to filter to the image nodes returned in the response. As you can see, images come in different sizes so you can select which one you which to use.

You wont get ONLY the picture back from the request, but you can easily grab it from the response.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I hope this works! thanks Matt Gifford :)

Comment: My pleasure. Let me know how you get on.